# What's the preferred method for connecting to a PPTP VPN under KDE?

Tags: 10.04, network-manager, kde, vpn, pptp

I have a remote worker who's got a Ubuntu 10.04.3 machine, running KDE. She was using KVPNC until she did an update over the weekend (I don't have the details on the update, she may have been using an older version of Ubuntu). Now KVPNC doesn't work - I've checked logs on our end and it isn't connecting to our VPN server.

I've asked her to try Network-Manager's VPN manager (network-manager-pptp-kde) and while she's got it installed and configured, she can't find a way to instantiate a connection. I don't have a KDE machine here to replicate the issue.

Is Network-Manager the right method to use for this? How do you actually start a connection?

Thanks!

Comment: KDE huh? I'll tinker with it and see what I can dig up.

Comment: you might need to reboot to have the system recognize network-manager-pptp-kde is installed... I had this issue on GNOME.

Answer (score 1):

From Network-Manager, select VPN connections, then click Configure VPN. On the next screen click Add and then Create to configure the PPTP VPN options. With my setup I had to ensure that I went into the Advanced area and selected Use Point to Point encryption and then turned off the Allow BSD data compression, Allow Deflate data compression, and use TCP header compression.

Your configuration might have to be different based on settings with the VPN server.